# Laravel 4 file not uploading

Tags: php, laravel-4

```
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/';
if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
        {
            $res = Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath);
            echo $destinationPath;

            if($res) 
            {
                echo '<br />good';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'bad'.$res;
            }
            exit;
        }
```

my enctype form is `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, the uploads folder exists and its access is `777`, the above statement returns `good`, the path is correct, what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: try to see if file is uploaded with `if (Input::hasFile('photo')) {...}`

Comment: code is ok, i've just tested. look at the size of the file...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $photo = Input::file('photo');

    if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
    {

        $file            = Input::file('photo');
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/';
        $filename        = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $user->logo_path = $filename;
    }


    $object->save();
```

//  Don't forget to save it using a save function, otherwise your hard work will be for nothing

// $object : use your object like user, car, ...